# using from <Form> tage for enter two date with same format

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, json

I want to get two date from user with same format(Date format is JALAL) by this code:((main part is bold))

```
<head>[enter image description here][1]
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="http://www.edak.cf/select_date_ir/datepicker.css" >
</head>

<body>

****<form action="" method="post">
  <div class="input-dte">
  From :  <input id="inputpickerr" class="input" name="From" type="text" placeholder="JALALI DATE" />
  To:  <input id="inputpicker" class="input" name="To" type="text" placeholder="JALALI DATE" />
  <input name="submit" type="submit" />
  </div>
</form>****


<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.edak.cf/select_date_ir/jalali.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.edak.cf/select_date_ir/calendar.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.edak.cf/select_date_ir/calendar-setup.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.edak.cf/select_date_ir/calendar-fa.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        Calendar.setup({
            inputField: "inputpicker",   // id of the input field
            inputField:    "inputpickerr",   // id of the input field
            button         :    "inputpicker",   // trigger for the calendar (button ID)
            button         :    "inputpickerr",   // trigger for the calendar (button ID)
            ifFormat       :    "%Y-%m-%d",       // format of the input field
            dateType       :    'jalali',
            weekNumbers    : false
        });
    </script>

</body>
```

but  JALALI format is working only for first input, and second input change to Gregorian date.Whereas both "input" is identical!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can't call the `.setup` method like that, Javascript objects can't have duplicate keys. You have to call it for each of the inputs separately:

```
Calendar.setup({
  inputField: 'inputpicker',
  button: 'inputpicker',
  ifFormat: '%Y-%m-%d',
  dateType: 'jalali',
  weekNumbers: false
});

Calendar.setup({
  inputField: 'inputpickerr',
  button: 'inputpickerr',
  ifFormat: '%Y-%m-%d',
  dateType: 'jalali',
  weekNumbers: false
});
```

Also if the `inputField` and `button` keys really contain IDs then you have another problem - IDs in HTML have to be unique.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your answer 
your are right, I forgot to tell  that subject : I add  "inputField: 'inputpickerr',
  button: 'inputpickerr',"  intractable . The original of that part is :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        Calendar.setup({
            inputField: "inputpicker",   // id of the input field
            button         :    "inputpicker",   // trigger for the calendar (button ID)ID)
            ifFormat       :    "%Y-%m-%d",       // format of the input field
            dateType       :    'jalali',
            weekNumbers    : false
        });
   </script>
```

Do you have any solution for my problem?